# Sending sequelize results through express after forEach loop has run

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, foreach, sequelize.js

I have a somewhat complicated sequelize query running in an express route, and I have a need to run a second query afterwards, to append needed data to the returned result:

```
//Get inboxes based on passed params
router.get('/:data', function(req, res, next) {
  let passedData = JSON.parse(req.params.data);
  models.fas.findAll({
    where: { current_stop: { $like: '%'+passedData.current_stop  +'%'},
             cert_class:   { $like: '%'+passedData.cert_class    +'%'},
             fis_yr:       { $like: '%'+passedData.fis_yr        +'%'},
             work_loc:     { $like: '%'+passedData.work_loc      +'%'},
             action_cd:    { $like: '%'+passedData.action_cd     +'%'},
             form_num:     { $like: '%'+passedData.form_num      +'%'},
             form_id:      'HRTF' },
    include: [
      { model: models.form,         as: 'form'         },
      { model: models.form_status,  as: 'form_status'  },
      { model: models.action_codes, as: 'action_codes' }
    ],
    order: ['form_num']
  }).then(function(response){

    response.forEach( item ) => {
      models.employees.findAll({
        attributes: [ 'fname', 'mname', 'lname' ],
        where: { empl_id: item.form[0].empl_id },
        order: [ 'empl_id' ]
      }).then(function(response){
        item.readableName = response;
      });
    });

  }).then(function(response){
    res.send(response);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    return next(error);
  });

});
```

The issue I'm having here (with the current setup) is that I need the forEach to finish appending data before I call res.send(response). If I take the last .then() off of this code and put res.send in the same block as the loop, the rest of the data gets sent correctly but no results from the employees table show. However, with the way it is set up above, nothing is sent to the response object that I am trying to send.

My question is twofold

**First:**

The employees table doesn't have any columns that match the original table (fas). Because of that, it's my understanding that I can't make an association between the two (which would get rid of the need for the forEach). Is that true?

**Second:**

If the loop is the right way to do this, how could I return the results from the forEach into the next .then and send it using res.send()?

Comment: In the first `.then()` from where is `response` coming from ?

Comment: models.fas.findAll({

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as usual I thought of a solution shortly after posting this. Turns out you can use nested includes in Sequelize, and I have an association between the employees table and another one I was already using. The solution looks like this:

```
//Get inboxes based on passed params
router.get('/:data', function(req, res, next) {

  let passedData = JSON.parse(req.params.data);
  models.hrtf_fas.findAll({
    where: { current_stop: { $like: '%'+passedData.current_stop  +'%'},
             cert_class:   { $like: '%'+passedData.cert_class    +'%'},
             fis_yr:       { $like: '%'+passedData.fis_yr        +'%'},
             work_loc:     { $like: '%'+passedData.work_loc      +'%'},
             action_cd:    { $like: '%'+passedData.action_cd     +'%'},
             form_num:     { $like: '%'+passedData.form_num      +'%'},
             form_id:      'HRTF'
    },
    include: [
      { model: models.form,         as: 'form',
        include: [{
          model: models.employees,  as: 'employees',
          attributes: [ 'fname', 'lname' ]
        }]        
      },
      { model: models.form_status,  as: 'form_status'  },
      { model: models.action_codes, as: 'action_codes' }
    ],
    order: ['form_num']
  }).then(function(response){
    res.send(response);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    return next(error);
  });
});
```

I need to do some concats, but I think this will do :)